# Equivalent of copyField of Solr on ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, solr, lucene, elasticsearch-5

Can someone tell me if there's an equivalent of Solr copyField directive on ElasticSearch?

I know there is the multi-field type:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html
It is nice when you want to apply multiple analyzers on the same field.

But it's not exactly the same.
Solr permits to "merge" multiple fields into one:

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="location" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="all" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<copyField source="*" dest="all"/>
```

---

This plugin is pretty promising:
https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-analysis-combo

Because it permits to get back the results as a single field when using an ElasticSearch multi value field.
But it's still not exactly the same because it doesn't permit to "merge" multiple fields.

---

I would like a combination of both Combo analyzer and Solr copyField.

I have a blog post model (title/description fields) and would like to copy both the title and description on a single field "blogContent" on which I'll apply 2 different analyzers.

Is there a solution in ElasticSearch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is [special `_all` field](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/all-field.html)  that by default gets a copy of all other fields. You can control inclusion into the `_all` field using `include_in_all` attribute. However, you are limited to one field like this. If you need more then one, you would need to handle it on the search side by searching multiple fields.

It's also possible to achieve functionality similar to copyField by using `multi_field` with the `"path": "just_name"` attribute:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-idx -d '{
    "settings": {
        "index": {
            "number_of_shards": 1,
            "number_of_replicas": 0
        }
    },
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "properties": {
                "first_name": {
                    "type": "multi_field",
                    "path": "just_name",
                    "fields": {
                        "first_name": {"type": "string", "index": "analyzed"},
                        "name": {"type": "string","index": "analyzed"}
                    }
                },
                "last_name": {
                    "type": "multi_field",
                    "path": "just_name",
                    "fields": {
                        "last_name": {"type": "string", "index": "analyzed"},
                        "name": {"type": "string","index": "analyzed"}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}'
echo
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/1 -d '{
    "first_name": "Sebastien",
    "last_name": "Lorber"
}'
echo
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test-idx/_refresh
echo
curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/_search?q=name:Sebastien"
echo
curl "localhost:9200/test-idx/doc/_search?q=name:Lorber"
```

Comment: I know the _all but it would be better to be able to create many different _all if needed

Comment: I agree, it would be a nice feature to have. Unfortunately, it's not implemented yet https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/1169

Comment: The `_all` feature has been deprecated in Elasticsearch 6+. They recommend using the `copy_to` mapping parameter.

Answer (score 6):

Elastic search supports copyTo:

- old link (dead): http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#copy-to
- current link in reference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html
- current link in guide: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-all.html

You can add an analyzer on the field you want to copy to.